# Grails: in domain, property declared as Long, should still add nullable:false in constraints

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

In Grails, it is said that by default, nullable is already set to false. But when I try to run `student.validate()` and not set studentId to nullable:false; validate cannot catch the error hence I get a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

Is my observation correct? or do you think I've messed up some code that's why validate cannot catch the error?

And if my observation is right. what is the reason behind it?

```
@Validateable
class Student {
Long studentId
.
.

static constraints = {

studentId nullable:false
.
.
}
}


def saveCreate(Student student){
        if (!student.validate()) {

            List errorList = buildErrorMessages(ErrorBean.getErrorBeans(student.errors), []);
            render([isSuccess: false, errors: errorList] as JSON);
            return;
        }

        student.save(flush: true);

        def Map studentInformation = [id: student.id, name: student.name];
        render([isSuccess: true, student: studentInformation] as JSON);

}
```

If i add this in static constraints

```
studentId nullable: false
```

when I run student.validate, validate can catch the error. If I didnt put it, validate will return true and will try to save the data.

Comment: Please add relevant code to question, we don't have a magic mirror that shows your code here on stack overflow.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia hi, I already add the code, thanks :)

Comment: what grails version are you using? Maybe you are changing nullable to true by default? Look for "grails.gorm.default.constraints" in your Config.groovy (or application.groovy in grails3)

Comment: @user3718614 Im using Grails ver 2.3.5. My Config.groovy doesn't contain that configuration. what else could I have done? Weird thing is, if I didnt declare a property which is a String to nullable = false, validate can catch the error it the user didn't provide a value for that property. So it works on String, but not in Long data type.

Comment: hard to say. Try to debug or add student.dump() before validation. Maybe you will see smth strange